# Sound stops working until full shutdown and startup, hardware or software?

Tags: audio

I have a Gigabyte G1 Sniper M5 motherboard with built-in Sound Blaster Recon3Di. I'm dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. A few times under Windows 7 the sound has stopped and doesn't come back on a soft reboot, even into Ubuntu which is on a different hard drive. The sound comes back when I fully shutdown the PC and start it back up (into either operating system).

Is there any way I can identify if this is a hardware or software issue? The fact that a soft reboot doesn't fix it even into a different OS really has me confused!

Comment: If you have the same issue in two different OSes (especially two that are as different as windows & ubuntu), then it is very likely a hardware (or low-level software?) issue.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but doing some more searching and I've found threads like this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519109 that show maybe it is possible for something to carry over in a soft reboot (in this example from Ubuntu to Windows) where the power is not cut in between...? It is certainly not something I knew was possible!